# Material Link inside Raised button not using react rounter routes

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using material-ui in my django project. I have different components to show different contents.
There is a button in my home page. When a use click on that button, I am trying to route him to signup page.

This is my button:

```
<RaisedButton containerElement={<Link to="/signup" />} 
label="GET STARTED" backgroundColor="#00BCD4" 
labelColor="#ffffff" style=`{buttonStyle} />
```

And this is my router setting:

```
render((
   <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
     <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
      <Route path="signup" component={SignUp} />
    </Route>

  </Router>), document.getElementById('app'));
```

The default page : http://127.0.0.1:8000/ is showing the index 'home' component but, when the user click the button, the not found page is opened from the django.

Did I miss anything to setup?

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to reproduce your issue with the details you provided.  You can look at the what I set up here: http://www.webpackbin.com/NJcI-Lbo-

I did notice that there a typo in your first code snippet (there is an unnecessary backtick). But I'm assuming that this was just a typo when entering into stackoverflow, as this shouldn't be causing the behavior you described.

```
style=`{buttonStyle}
```

It does not seem like this is related to `<Link />` and `<RaisedButton />`. Instead, it sounds like there may be some configuration issue from your local web server's end.

Does going directly to http://127.0.0.1:8000/signup work?